# Aggregation different value to xml with Xquery

Tags: xml, grouping, aggregate, xquery

Im continuing working with Xquerys to transform XML files.

This is my problem
In XML file like:

```
<radioequipment>
  <userLabel>FIRST</userLabel>
  <siteId>10.10.10.10</siteId>
  <siteName>ABCD</siteName>
  <displayedName>Port 4/1</displayedName>
</radioequipment >

<radioequipment>
  <userLabel>FIRST</userLabel>
  <siteId>10.10.10.10</siteId>
  <siteName>ABCD</siteName>
  <displayedName>Port 3/1</displayedName>
</radioequipment>
```

I would like obtain a result like this:

```
<radioequipment.RadioPortSpecifics xmlns="xmlapi_1.0">
    <userLabel>FIRST</userLabel>
    <siteId>10.10.10.10.</siteId>
    <siteName>ABCD</siteName>
    <ports>     
       <port1>Port 4/1</port1>
       <port2>Port 3/1</port2>
    </ports>
</radioequipment.RadioPortSpecifics>
```

My objetive is group one tag, after compare that the TAGs are equals (one item qith 2 ports, in this case). 
The autoincremental name for "port", can be the same name?

After "googling" I didnt find anything similar, 
Can you hep me? Any Clue?

Thanks in advance for yout help!!

Comment: Do you have access to an XQuery 3.0+ processor supporting "group by"?

Comment: with group by, not sure how to change default tags